# Android: How to record mp3 radio (audio) stream

Tags: android, mp3, audio-streaming, audio-recording, internet-radio

My favorite Radio station plays a radio audio stream in mp3 format. In my android application I can receive and play it without any problem.

How can I implement a recording function? I want to record the mp3 radio stream to my Android phones SD-Card.

I tried the MediaRecorder Class without any result...

[Android Developer: MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

...

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

...

Unfortunately I cannot choose something like:

`mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MP3_STREAM);`  ... ;-)

How can I record a mp3 radio stream? Thanks for any help or code snippets...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you should read audio stream "byte by byte" and then place it into new file? Like a simple file copy operation, using inputstream-outputstream.

Comment: Perfect! Reading the audio stream "byte by byte" is the solution. Thank you!!

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384161/5856328 to read stream data but I got inputStream.read()) == -1 why data is streaming. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 23):

Perfect! Reading the audio stream "byte by byte" is the solution. Thank you!!

Here my code snippets:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://myradio,com/stream.mp3");
        inputStream = url.openStream();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "url.openStream()");

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FileOutputStream: " + outputSource);

        int c;

        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bytesRead=" + bytesRead);
            fileOutputStream.write(c);
            bytesRead++;
        }
```

Comment: have u created an app for this?

Comment: How have you used this for the MediaPlayer to use this AND save the files at the same time?  Also, how is "bytesRead" is set?

Comment: Playing and recordig are both async tasks. You can just start both without problems. bytesRead is just a counter (int) for debugging.

Comment: Have you face problem that recorder is recording music fast than player playing? using this byte by byte approch?

Comment: No I did not face this problem. I just read the inputStream as it comes in and it will be written in a FileOutputStream. The resulting mp3 plays fine.

Comment: I tried to read stream data but I got inputStream.read()) == -1. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Not really an idea. Maybe it's an issue when your URL starts with "https". Some Android versions needs to handle this special.