# How to record an FM audio in android programming?

Tags: android

i need to record the songs being played by a FM app.
I checked the MediaRecorder.AudioSource but could not find what to use for setAudioSource

can anyone please help me?

thanks,

Comment: Perhaps use AudioSource.MIC? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#MIC I think that your question is somewhat related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178996/mediarecorder-record-calls-application

Comment: AFAIK an FM radio audio source is only available internally as OEM/platform-specific extension (if it's available at all). If you've got a device based on a Qualcomm-platform you could try using `9` as the audio source (see e.g. https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java?h=jb_mr1#n197), but beware of the fact that you're then relying on things that may change or isn't available.

Comment: See [How to record an FM audio in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500925/how-to-record-an-fm-audio-in-android) for an answer.

Comment: Hi Did you find the solution for this... ?Did you find the how to get the Audio source ?