# Android play and record radio stream simultaneously

Tags: java, android, websocket, stream, webserver

I have Android application, which stream radio stream with m3u extension. It is playing this stream in MediaPlayer through method **setDatasource(url)**. Of course, this works greaet because I don't need to take a care about reading inputstream, buffer that, repeatedly send to the MediaPlayer with seeking the last position and so on.

But now I need to stream and also record the stream. How should I do that? What are your recommendations?

- Like use **NanoHTTPD** (but how, where should I start to study own webserver logic)
- Or use **SockerHandler** somehow?
- Or any other solution? I don't know even, where should I start to study this problem.

Many thanks

Comment: here is a possible answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381969/android-how-to-record-mp3-radio-audio-stream/5384161#5384161

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet it doesn't help, because what if the url path looks like **http://42.1.123.45:8080/128** ? In that case, the url doesn't connect to the stream url. What then?

Comment: you need to add http/https before the url.. i am also using an ip address for the url  for live video streaming and it works great. Are you able to stream the audio?