# Immediate Audio Input & Output Android

Tags: android, audio, microphone, audiorecord, audiotrack

In my Android App, I would like to take in some audio from the mic of the smartphone and play it immediately, live, like a microphone, with no lag. I am currently thinking of using `AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack` classes (from what I have read), but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

I checked out some other questions on Stack Overflow but they don't exactly answer what I would like to do. And most are from 2012.

So how can I use these classes to input and output audio simultaneously?

**ALSO:** I had a look at the `MediaRecorder API`, but from what I read, that requires you to save the audio to a file, which I don't want to do. Can it be tweeked to meet my requirements? Or am I better off just using `AudioRecord`?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated code below as @Pradip Pramanick suggested:

```
final Thread record = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                MediaRecorder microphone = new MediaRecorder();
                microphone.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    microphone.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                microphone.setOutputFile(filename);
                microphone.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                try {
                    microphone.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                microphone.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final Thread play = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(filename);
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I am getting an `Illegal State Exception | Start failed: -38`. But I am calling `microphone.start` after `microphone.prepare`... What seems to be the problem? I searched other threads which said there might be other background apps using the microphone. I searched my device: Moto X Play (3rd Gen) and found none. (I even turned off "Ok Google" voice recognition, but the error kept coming).

**ERROR LOG:**

Here is the log-cat showing the most recent errors:

```
01-31 09:37:21.064 344-3339/? E/MediaPlayerService: offset error
01-31 09:37:21.065 1835-1922/com.synerflow.testapp E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player

01-31 09:37:21.065 1835-1922/com.synerflow.testapp I/Player: player.prepare() has failed
01-31 09:37:21.065 1835-1922/com.synerflow.testapp W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

The IO Exception seems to be at `player.setDataSource(filename)`, the filename variable is a string: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "\voice.3gp"`

Comment: Should just be able to transfer streams something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381969/android-how-to-record-mp3-radio-audio-stream/5384161#5384161. Maybe with a small buffer too. Just wondering why really - and whether you would suffer audio feedback quite badly if you did.

Comment: Yes the problem is due to the fact that player and recorder are both trying to read and write the same file. Use a small buffer that can hold say 1ms of audio. Then use two synchronized threads: recorder thread puts data into buffer and sets a flag. Player thread on checking the flag start playing. Refer to the classical Producer-Consumer problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Google Oboe.

> Oboe is a C++ library that makes it easy to build high-performance audio apps on Android.

Oboe has already an example for "Immediate Audio Input & Output Android"

> LiveEffect Sample
>
> This sample simply loops audio from the input stream to the output stream to
> demonstrate the usage of the 2 stream interfaces.

https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/LiveEffect

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can think it can be done in a very simple way. I haven't tried it,but you try it. I think it'll work:

Create two threads one for recording another for playing.
Say the threads are TRecord and TPlay.

In TRecord's run method do this :

```
public void run(){
        MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //todo
        }

        mRecorder.start();
}
```

And it TPlay's run method do this :

```
public void run() {
MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //todo
        }
}
```

Now on mainactivity simply create two threads. First start the TRecord thread then Tplay . Try it.

here is the code for file extension:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

Comment: Hi, what is the mFileName in this case? Is it a predefined file? Also, I'd like to get rid of the file after I'm done speaking. How can this be done?

Comment: Also, what should the extension of the file be in this case? Could you include the code that sets up the output file / data source?

Comment: Hi, It is giving me an error: `Start Failed: -38 | IllegalStateException`. But I am calling start after prepare. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Turns out you can not use 'MediaRecorder' cant be used when some other service using the mic. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971817/mediarecorder-start-failed-38/) .  Check if any similar thing is happening. Else use some other class such as AudioRecord.

Comment: You can also try doing either of the tasks (record/play) using AsynkTask and check if it meets your latency requirements

Comment: I put the code in AsyncTasks. It doesn't give any errors (initially, after I stop and start again, it gives an IOException) but it still does not work.

Comment: It would be better if you give some details like logcat. I think the IO exception is caused by synchronization problems because ultimately you are reading and writing from the same stream. Try using buffer .There is Producer-Consumer solution for threads. Check [this](http://crunchify.com/java-producer-consumer-example-handle-concurrent-read-write/)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually really tricky on Android. Google themselves have a very good (but slightly long) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3kfEeMZ65c&feature=youtu.be) explaining the issues.

They also have [a page explaining their latency testing methods and benchmarks](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/latency_measurements.html) for various devices.

Essentially, stock Android can't do zero-latency audio, however there's nothing stopping hardware partners from adding the required hardware and platform extensions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I have not run this.

```
      recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
      RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
      RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize * BytesPerElement);

    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

      try {
          int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO , RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
          byte[] sData = new byte[bufferSize];
          AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, intSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
          while(isRecording){
          recorder.read(sData, 0, bufferSize);  //isRecording = false; onStop button

          if (at!=null) { 
              at.play();
              // Write the byte array to the track
              at.write(sData, 0, sData.length); 
              at.stop();
              at.release();
          }
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
  }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
```

Comment: Its part of one of my project earlier, and is working fine. You need to assemble it properly and initialize variables like sample rate 44100 etc. :)

Comment: So, it works. But the voice is very cracky and extremely odd. Any reason why this could be happening? Also, how much is `BytesPerElement`?

Comment: Try sample rate 44100 and `RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` . I hope you have considered buffersize = `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING)`

If it works, dont forget to mark as an answer. :)

Comment: Hi, I have exactly those parameters as the sample rate and encoding. It's still giving a cracky audio. What is BytesPerElement and what is the value? Also my channel is CHANNEL_IN_MONO. Is that correct?

Comment: `bytesperelement=2` channel is correct.  You may refer developer android website for more options

Comment: the voice quality and latency is still terrible.

Comment: Then you need to try with different sample rates and modes.