# How to record internal audio on Android devices or record MediaPlayer Audio Stream?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiorecord

I'm currently trying to **record an audio stream** which is played in `MediaPlayer`.

Actually I found some blog-post, saying it's **not possible because of security / copyright reasons**, but I couldn't find any official statements from Android/Google docs. Furthermore, there are screen capture **apps like Mobizen which can record internal audio** (at least Samsung devices seems to work).

So can someone tell, if

1. internal audio is officially not allowed / supported?
2. it's possible to record a stream with `AudioRecorder` which is played in `MediaPlayer`?

I'm not so sure if I'm entering the dark side at the moment?

What I already tried to answer the 2nd question:

- recorded different `MediaRecorder.AudioSource`, but all record the microphone
- found [byte by byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381969/android-how-to-record-mp3-radio-audio-stream/5384161#5384161) for recording, but this is not working with `MediaPlayer`

Comment: It's true that Mobizen seems to do that but maybe they are using screencasting API to that?

Comment: I don't think that the official Android APIs allow what you want. [Even Mobizen acknowledges this](https://support.mobizen.com/hc/en-us/articles/226494547-Can-I-record-Internal-Sound-). My best guess is that Mobizen is probably using extra APIs that only Samsung and LG phones support (but if so, I haven't seen any public documentation of such APIs). This older post also discusses the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676142/record-android-audio-output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Coming with the new Android 10 API, there finally is an `AudioPlaybackCapture` API.

> This API gives apps the ability to copy the audio being played by other apps. This feature is the analogue of screen capture, but for audio.

I personally haven't tested it, yet, but here are the required steps to capture audio, based on the dev guide.

Permissions needed to capture audio:

- The app must have the [`RECORD_AUDIO`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECORD_AUDIO) permission.
- The app must bring up the prompt displayed by [`MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager#createScreenCaptureIntent()), and the user must approve it.
- The capturing and playing apps must be in the same user profile.

To capture the audio, you then need to build an [`AudioRecord`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) object and add the [`AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration) to it:

1. Call [`AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder.build()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder.html#build()) to build an [`AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration).
2. Pass the configuration to the `AudioRecord` by calling [`setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.Builder.html#setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration)).

You can also constrain the capture by `AUDIO_USAGE` or a `UID`, see: [Constraining capture by audio content](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture#constraining_capture_by_audio_content)

I highly recommend that you check out the [Android Dev Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture).

### Limitations

**09/01/2020 Update:** Android 10.0 now accounts for 29.04% of the Android market share, according to StatCounter.

[image: Mobile & Tablet Android Version Market Share Worldwide]

*Mobile & Tablet Android Version Market Share Worldwide, from July 2019 to July 2020. Source: [StatCounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/worldwide)*

---

**Old answer:** Very few devices are running on Android, 10. Google has not released yet the market share, but we can guess that it is at most less than 10%, which is the market share of Android 9.0.

[image: Data collected during a 7-day period ending on May 7, 2019. Any versions with less than 0.1% distribution are not shown.]

*Data collected during a 7-day period ending on May 7, 2019. Any versions with less than 0.1% distribution are not shown. Source: [Distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards)*

Comment: can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196648/record-internal-audio-not-working-for-tv-box