# Record internal audio not working for TV BOX

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have an app where one device shares his internal audio to another android device using the Sound Capture API (that was introduced in the Android API level 29). This app is working fine on mobile devices.

However, when I try the app on an android box (which has access to the Android level 29 API) which is connected to a TV via HDMI, it doesn't seem to receive the audio signal. So either the audio can't be transferred or there is an issue when setting the audio format channel mask.

Below is my code:

```kotlin
val config = AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration.Builder(AudioCaptureService.mediaProjection!!)
    .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
    .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_UNKNOWN)
    .addMatchingUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
    .build()

val buffer = Buffer()

val audioFormat = AudioFormat.Builder()
    .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
    .setSampleRate(buffer.sampleRate)
    .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
    .build()

val record = AudioRecord.Builder()
    .setAudioFormat(audioFormat)
    .setAudioPlaybackCaptureConfig(config)
    .setBufferSizeInBytes(buffer.size)
    .build()
```

Comment: The issue might be HDMI and if, there's probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler so how can i overcome this issue because i found some of tv boxes support internal system sound recording too

Comment: Haven't you read what I've wrote? Just don't use HDMI or even that box; record on the same machine. It's not even the recording-settings, but the signal is usually encrypted, which means you could in best case record the line-out.

Comment: Thanks @MartinZeitler , but i have to use box because this app is developed for this box and box only connected through hdmi cable so i will try your suggestion by line out i will try to connect speakers and let you know about that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I can see does not come from your code but rather from the API you are using. When reading the spec (see [Playback capture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture) on the Android developers website), there is this line:

> This API gives apps the ability to copy the audio being played by other apps.

If I understand correctly the design of your app, you stream an audio feed **from** an android device (let's call it the sender) **to** another device (this one will be the receiver). The sound capture step occurs on the **sender**, the device that sends the stream to the receiver. Not on the receiver.

Now, if you wish to record the stream coming from a TV (no matter how you get this stream) with your app, you would need to install your app on the TV because it is the one that sends the signal. If you could do that, you would reproduce the scheme **sender -> receiver** and everything would (should) work fine.

However, as I understand it, you are only able to install the app on the receiver (the Android box), making the audio capture impossible with this design.

To solve this, you would need to record an input stream with the [`MediaRecorder` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) and the correct `AudioSource` (see [`MediaRecorder.AudioSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource)). There is a guide on how to record audio right here: [MediaRecorder overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder).

Comment: Thanks @Gaspacchio for comment i already install the app in my tv box and using it as sender actually the issue i found is that it failed to receive audio due to hdmi connectivity and failed to capture audio from it , and its working fine in mobiles .i tried many things  here setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO) but no luck :(

Comment: And TV BOX have android 10 too so i try to record internal sound

Comment: Well, I don't know how I can help you more now @RuhiThakur. Coul you could give us the android box model you are using?

Comment: Thanks @Puka for your help i can record now.