# Live phone Call caption / transcription (speech to text) on Android

Tags: android, speech-to-text

**This question is to help the "Hard of hearing community" so that they can READ the phone/mobile call because they can not hear it.**

Android 11 provides an API "AudioPlaybackCaptureConfiguration". This API gives apps the ability to copy the audio being played by other apps.

Google also implemented the same on Pixel mobiles as shownn here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hb3p8LZIq8 . But it has few limitations -

1. It supports only english language, How to enable support for the regional language
2. The current implementation translates voice to text using a local mobile engine i.e. voice is not going to google server(all the processing is happening offline in mobile itself), so accuracy is also low.

After seeing a lot of posts here it seems developers are facing issue while implementing the same to capture the caller voice and then transcibe it due to some restriction by Google.

[How to record internal audio on Android devices or record MediaPlayer Audio Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543466/how-to-record-internal-audio-on-android-devices-or-record-mediaplayer-audio-stre/60078178#60078178)

Is there anyway to capture the caller voice (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture#allowing_playback_capture) ? Like in the youtube video I shared above, Google must be capturing caller voice and its offline engine is processing that voice and converting it to text. So can we capture caller voice using some way and then send that voice to some server API or to Google Live Transcribe app (or whatever it is) for better accuracy and then the converted text will be displayed on the screen (as per user choice of language).

I am also a developer though not a mobile one. So some terminology may be wrong , please excuse it and provide your suggestion.

Can we modify the Android source code itself according to our requirement and remove that limitation so that we can achieve what we want to do even if it require to build custom Android OS ?

Comment: This question isn't specific. What problem are you having? Do you not know how to get the audio stream for the call? Will the playback capture not recognise the voice in the audio stream?

Comment: @user3252344 - I want to capture the caller voice(please note it will be consider as system call) and I think as of now Android is not giving any option to capture caller voice which we can feed as input to caption writing application( for example Google LIVE transcribe).