# Only record audio from device itself in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio

I want to record audio from the **device only**, such as the music from the device.

I had try package `sound_stream`, but it record all audio from microphone, it's not what I need.

Is there any way I can record audio from device itself only?

Comment: Try using this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078178/16973338

Comment: Also have a look on this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound